# When is the image of an algebraic map into $\mathbb{CP}^n$ is a complex projecitve submanifold.

Tags: complex-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $M\subset \mathbb{CP}^n$ be a complex projective manifold and $f:M\to \mathbb{CP}^m$ an algebraic map. Are there known sufficient conditions for $f(M)$ to be a projective submanifold?

I have in mind the Veronese maps $\mathbb{CP^n}\to \mathbb{CP}^N$, but I want to know if there are ways to construct maps that give complex projective manifolds.

Comment: f(M) is always a projective subvariety (closed, reduced and irreducible). The question of whether it is nonsingular or not depends on what f and M are, obviously.